# How can we record a video with a custom crop in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, video, camera, resize, record

I am using the Flutter [camera package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) and I am wondering how to record a square shape video. There are easy means to do this with an image (at least to process the image after the capture) but I have not found a way for the videos. Does someone have any clues ?